# How to use symfony console progress Helper?

Tags: php, symfony, console, progress-bar

Going by the example [Symfony Progress Helper](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/console/helpers/progresshelper.html)

I'm not really sure how to use this. I'm using usleep because I want the progress bar to run until the task is finished. Say the task is a method that does many other things and when it is finished it returns true. When it returns true I want to use setCurrent to finish the progress bar out.

```
$progress = $this->getHelperSet()->get('progress');

$progress->start($this->output, 100);

$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 100) {
    usleep(100000);

    $progress->advance();

}

//do stuff and return true when it's done
if($this->doStuff()) $progress->setCurrent(100);

$progress->finish();
```

It is not clear to me in the docs how this works. If I put my method inside the loop it will get run 100 times. But if I put it outside the loop then the loop will run 100 times before running my method. Plus if I put it outside $progress->finish() I get an error that I must start() the progress bar which makes sense but if I put it inside finish() I get a logicException " You can't regress the progress bar"

Thanks for any help. Example usage would be great.

**UPDATE:**
Maybe this is not possible.

Let me explain what I'm trying to do to clear it up some.

I want a progress bar to run on the screen. It's set to itterate longer than doStuff() will actually take to run. doStuff() is basically a fire() method in my class to do a bunch of other stuff including downloading and copying a file. But doStuff() only runs once. I need the progress bar to be running the whole time doStuff() is running but when doStuff() is finished I want to be able to either advance the progress bar to the end or just terminate it regardless of where it is in it's loop.

I tried putting progress->advance() inside my doStuff() method but it still requires a loop because it only advances once. So this is why I need doStuff() to be separate from the progress bar loop but be able to terminate it from doStuff().

Comment: you don't need to use `setCurrent()`, you should call `advance()` inside the loop where you are doing your processing (I assume somewhere inside `doStuff()`)

Comment: I don't understand. doStuff is not a loop. It's a single long running process that calls other methods, instantiates classes etc. But while it's running I want the progress bar run across the screen. This is why I though I would use setCurrent to advance it to the end after my doStuff is finished.

Comment: that's what I'm saying, you need to integrate your `ProgressHelper` into your `doStuff()` method, so that you can increment it during the process, your `while` loop is advancing the progress before the `doStuff()` method has actually been called. Is your `doStuff()` method actually taking that long to run that it needs a `ProgressHelper`?

Comment: I see now. I don't need a loop at all. Just a callback to advance the bar after each task in doStuff()

Answer (score 0):

The answer thanks to JamesHalsall comments is the progress bar doesn't work this way. If I wanted to loop through a single task or group of tasks several times the example from Symfony would work.

But in this case with only one task, the doStuff() method I need to pass a callback to doStuff() so doStuff() can advance the progress bar. There is no need for a loop here. Also found that advance method takes an integer as a argument for how many steps to advance.

So with a little basic math and a callback this is actually. With the progress bar set to 100 and 4 tasks in doStuff() 100/4 = 25 is how many steps to advance the progress bar.

Here is an example that is working for me. Of course exceptions thrown in the 4 tasks will stop everything so there is no worry of the progress bar completing even though a particular task failed.

```
    protected function update()
    {
        $this->progress = $this->getHelperSet()->get('progress');
        $this->progress->setBarCharacter('<comment>=</comment>');
        $this->progress->setBarWidth(50);
        $this->progress->start($this->output, 100);
        $done = false;


        $result = false;

        $advance = function($steps)
        {
            $this->progress->advance($steps);
        };

        $result = $this->doStuff($advance);

        $this->progress->finish();

        if($result === true)
        {
            $this->displayOutput("I be done foo!");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->displayOutput("Somethin went wrong foo!");
        }

    }


    protected function doStuff($callback)
    {
        //simulate tasks with usleep
        //perfom task 1
        usleep(500000);
        $callback(25);

        //perform task 2
        usleep(500000);
        $callback(25);

        //task 3
        usleep(5000000);
        $callback(25);

        //task 4
        usleep(3000000);
        $callback(25);

        //at this point the progress bar is finished so you can return whatever is appropriate here
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting 100 as an arbitrary number that has no reference to anything else.

You could call a getter in doStuff that would allow you to update the parent command.

```
$progress = $this->getHelperSet()->get('progress');

$progress->start($this->output, 100);

$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 100) {
    if (null === $this->doStuff() || $this->doStuff()->getCount() >= $i) {
        $progress->advance();
    }
}
```